# how to install Zend Framework in wamp

Tags: zend-framework

I am very new in Zend framework and I want to learn this framework.
So I have downloaded ZendFramework-2.0.5 version but I dont know how can I install it, run it and work on it.

I want to install it into WAMP server , Eclipse IDE and window XP os.

Please tell me all the useful step to achieve it.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to work with a library would be to add it to your php.ini include path, like :

```
include_path = ".;c:\php\includes;C:\wamp\apps\ZendFramework-2.0.5\library"
```

I would recommand you to put it in the Apps folder of wamp, this way it's not project specific. The other way would be to put the Zend folder from the bundle in the library folder of a Zend project

To be able to use the ZF tool (create project and a few other things) you also need to add to your environment variables the path to the folder containing the zf.bat command line tool

Terms might differ since I have a french version of Windows, but translation should be accurate enough

1. right-click on your computer and select properties
2. Advanced systems settings
3. Environment variables
4. In the section `Variables for user ...`, click on create and name the new variable `ZF` and set `C:\wamp\apps\ZendFramework-2.0.5\bin` as the value
5. In the section `System variables` find the key `path` and add the same path at the end (make sure to put a ; before pasting your new path)
6. Start a command line tool in admin (right-click on icon and select run as administrator) and type zf, you should get the help text from the ZF tool

From there you should be able to create a new project where you want by following the quick start given in the documentation

You might want to create a new [virtual host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting) for your project as well

You can then try the follow [tutorial](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2-tutorial/) (one of the bests)

Comment: Very very thanks for your valuable suggestion. I followed all your steps but Please also tell me that after doing these step How can I test it that whether it is install correctly or not and also How can I start with a simple project like hello world. Thanks in advanced

Comment: @manas_Singh For a quick start tutorial on Zend, you can refer to this: 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html

Comment: @manas _Singh : you can download the skeleton app for ZF2 http://framework.zend.com/downloads/skeleton-app and then follow from there